# Building a location hierarchy of counts

Tags: java, java-8

I have the following Location hierarchy:

```
public class Location {
   public Location parentLocation;
   public String name;
   public int id;
}

List<Location> listOfCities; // This list strictly contains all "city" level locations like Chicago, Atlanta etc.
```

Let's assume for a second that the parentLocation can only be the country and the parentLocation of a country is null. ie. If i have a location for Chicago, the parentLocation for a Chicago location object would be USA and the chain would terminate there because the location USA has parentLocation = null. I have a list of city level location objects and I would like to get the following counts:

```
USA (20)
  - Chicago (12)
  - New York (1)
  - Oregon (5)
  - Atlanta (2)
Mexico (1)
  - Puebla (1)
```

Is there a convenient way in Java8 to get a jsonable object that would represent the counts hierarchy I described above for a given list of city locations? My attempt:

```
// Get counts of all cities in listOfCities (ie. Chicago -> 12)
Map<String, Integer> cityCounts = listOfCities.stream()
.map(Location::name)
.collect(Collectors.toMap(city -> city, city -> 1, Integer::sum));
```

I am unsure how exactly to get the "rolled-up" counts by parentLocation though and get everything into a single clean response object that can be walked in a fashion as pretty-printed above.

Comment: Does Chicago have 12 because there are 12 other cities where Chicago is the parent? Is `listOfCities` a `List<Location>` of all the locations, parents and non-parents?

Comment: @4castle Chicago has 12 because there are 12 cities with String name = "Chicago". The listOfCities is a List<Location> of all non-parents (ie. city level Location objects). There is no location level outside of city and the parentLocation of a city = country.

Comment: Thanks, that clears things up. Will `USA` be included as a key in the output `Map`?

Comment: I'm not sure how to represent the output actually. I would need to be a jsonable tree-esque object that can be passed around in as close to the format as my sample above. My code snippet was an attempt to at least get some of the information I would need in my final Object. This final object could then be walked at the country level with sub nodes for each city, all with counts at each node

Comment: Seems like you're putting the cart before the horse. First figure out what structure you're trying to build, then let's see if Java 8 can help

Comment: I think the final Object will be a tree of sorts with the each country being a root node with one sublevel representing cities in each root country. Each leaf in first level the tree is labelled with the count of cities in the root country.

Comment: Perhaps you want a `Map<String, Map<String, Integer>>`? The outer map would be the countries, and the inner map would be the cities and their counts. Please [edit] your question with your desired output structure.

Comment: That could work as long as it could be jsonified into valid Json objects with country as key with an array of city values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can produce a `Map<String, Map<String, Long>>`, with country names in the outer map, and city names/counts in the inner map.

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*;

Map<String,Map<String,Long>> cityCountsByCountry = listOfCities
    .stream()
    .collect(groupingBy(city -> city.parentLocation.name,
                 groupingBy(city -> city.name,
                     counting())));
```

This would produce a structure resembling this JSON:

```
{
  "USA": {
    "Chicago": 12,
    "New York": 1,
    "Oregon": 5,
    "Atlanta": 2
  },
  "Mexico": {
    "Puebla": 1
  }
}
```

Comment: need to add null check in grouping by...  `city ->  city.parentLocation == null ? city.name : city.parentLocation.name`

Comment: @Bolzano All of the elements in `listOfCities` are cities. None of them will have `null` as a parent.

Comment: meh.. i thought there was a bigger challenge like the list contains all but nvm this works as expected then, nice one.

Comment: @Bolzano If the list did contain all locations, then I would put a `filter` before the `collect` which filters out elements with a `null` parent. Optionally, then I would go back and give any countries with no cities an empty inner map.

Comment: in the end this doesn't change the list that you work in.

Comment: What about the rollup count?

Comment: @shmosel The totals for the countries could be found just by summing the counts in each inner map. That operation is pretty simple, and it would be redundant to put it in the JSON since it can be derived.